# Sum of a two dimensional array

Tags: sum, fortran

I have this 2D array L(i,j). How can I sum all the elements depending of `i` and make the result as a function of `j`

I did :

```
 do j=1,10
  do i =1,30
   T(j) = Sum( L(:,j)
  end do 
 end do
```

Is that ok?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost... you don't use `i` (and you don't need to), and you are missing one bracket:

```
do j=1,10
  T(j) = Sum( L(:,j) )
enddo ! j
```

You could also use the dimension parameter in [`sum`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SUM.html) to do this operation in one line:

```
T = sum( L, dim=1 )
```

However, I find that very difficult to read and would stick with the loop - it shouldn't make a difference in terms of performance.

Comment: Sometimes it is faster using the loops than not.